# xpages column showCheckbox

Tags: xpages

There is a `viewPanel` having a column with `showCheckbox="true"`.

Is it possible to restrict the users to select only one row/document  ( and not multiple rows/docs. ) listed by the viewPanel?

Comment: Yes, using javascript/jQuery, but I don't believe you can do that serverside.  If you are comfortable writing client javascript you can figure it out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not in a View Panel. The View Panel is designed to offer a quick, simple approach with restricted functionality.

An alternative (possibly better) approach may be to have another column with a link or image that triggers whatever functionality you need. That will allow users to trigger functionality with a single click rather than two. The View Panel allows you to place controls in columns instead of just mapping to a column in the underlying view.

Alternatively, you could add a checkbox manually to a column, map to a scoped variable, and check/uncheck programmatically.

Answer (score 3):

Paul's probably right on. My alternative for you is to use a repeat control.  You can make it look however you want.  Including a view control.

I have an example of this in this NotesIn9 show:  http://notesin9.com/index.php/2011/07/11/notesin9-ee-009-using-java-hashmaps-and-treemaps-with-xpages/

Now in my example I did multiple values.  But if instead of a HashMap or ArrayList if you kept your "selected" document id in a single value field like just a scoped variable..  then you'd get what you want.  One document at a time.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Paul Stephans (also upvoted his answer because I think it would be the Nest solution) but if you insist on adding such a functionality to your viewPanel you can do this by adding a client side script to prevent the user from selecting more then one element:

First add the `styleClass="rowCB"` to your checkbox row and insert this code to your xpage:

```
<xp:scriptBlock>
    <xp:this.value><![CDATA[dojo.ready(function(){
    dojo.query('.rowCB>input').connect("onclick", function(evt){ 
              var target = evt.target.id;
              if(!window.crrCheckedElement){
                window.crrCheckedElement = evt.target.id;
              }else if(window.crrCheckedElement != target){
                    alert("You can select only one item!");
                    evt.target.checked = false;
              }else if(window.crrCheckedElement == target){
                  window.crrCheckedElement = "";
              }
            })
    });]]></xp:this.value>
</xp:scriptBlock>
```

Maby the code needs some improvement but this should be your way to go.

Comment: CSJS is the way to go. Just want to point out you may get in trouble with paging...

Comment: @MichaelSaiz I will give it a try and let you know.

Answer (score 1):

though maybe not the best solution, here is one possibility.

```
function deselectOtherDocs(viewName, currentDocId) {
var viewPanel:com.ibm.xsp.component.xp.XspViewPanel = getComponent(viewName);
var selectedIds = viewPanel.getSelectedIds();
for(var i=0; i<selectedIds.length; ++i){
if(selectedIds[i]!=currentDocId){viewPanel._xspSetIdUnchecked(selectedIds[i])}
return;
}
```

fire this off when a doc is checked and pass the view control name and the current doc's unid.

pardon any typos. I am writing from my phone.

edit: if you don't have to use a view control, then David Leedy's suggestion is the way to go. store the selected unid in a scope variable and let that determine which repeat row's box is selected. you might also consider using a radio button instead of a checkbox, since the former is understood as a single selector by users.